# bitcoin for my android app

Tags: client, android, website-integration

I am panning to build an android app for my college cafeteria where student can buy coffee using bitcoin and the can recharge the bitcoin through some source(from college bank).

please give me some idea how to implement this app. And is there any good tutorial related to this topic.

Comment: Neither sure if I understand what you are asking, nor sure whether your question is a good fit for SE, but there are already multiple Android wallets out there that allow you to receive and send funds.

Comment: Long before you implement the application, you need to figure out how the system as a whole is going to work. For example, where is the bank going to get the Bitcoins it sells? And how will the bank sell Bitcoins while still complying with the various regulations it's subject to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to create a custom bitcoin application, forking from an existing app should reduce reinventing the wheel and can act as a learning resource. For example, here are two open-source Android bitcoin apps whose source you could grab:

- http://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/
- http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinspinner/

The simplest solution that would serve a `bank=>bitcoin=>coffee` arrangement would be only implementing a `bitcoin=>coffee` app for students; and a `bitcoin=>coffee` notification app for the cafe.

Save yourself the headache of handling fiat money in the app by either leaving the conversion of fiat currency to other more generic unbranded Android bitcoin apps or integrating an existing bitcoin provider into the app (e.g. Coinbase).

Please note that Android is *not a particularly secure platform* for bitcoin wallets - this is simply because Android by-design allows users to have true control over their phone; but most users will never lock down their phone and apply security hygiene to the necessary extent*. If you go forward with this, the main [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site could also prove useful.

<sub>* Apple users shouldn't feel too smug :-) iPhone are locked down for monopoly control. User security is a convenient side-effect.</sub>